# Explain the underlying processing of `multioutput=[0.3, 0.7]` in sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

based on the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-absolute-error)

> The mean_absolute_error function computes mean absolute error, a risk metric corresponding to the expected value of the absolute error loss or L1-norm loss.

I understand the process for 2 "vectors"

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
>>> y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]
>>> y_pred = [2.5, 0.0, 2, 8]
>>> mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

which is to add all the absolute difference between peer elements in each vector, and then divided by the length of the vector.

this code is exactly underlying processing of sklearn.mean_absolute_error for 2 "vectors"

```
res = 0
for t,p in zip(y_true, y_pred):
    res = res + np.abs(t-p)
res/4
```

what I cannot understand is this processing

```
>>> mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred, multioutput=[0.3, 0.7])
0.85
```

Could someone please illustrate the underlying processing of `multioutput=[0.3, 0.7]` part?

Answer (score 1):

It's explained a little [higher on that same docs page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics).

If you want to see explicitly what it does, you can see it in the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/regression.py#L189): `mean_absolute_error()` ends by calling [numpy's `average()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html?highlight=average#numpy.average) function with weights equal to `multioutput`.

So `multioutput` is just a way to tell `mean_absolute_error()` that when calculating the mean error, the errors on some of the quantities should count more towards that averge than others.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, `multioutput=[0.3, 0.7]` is the `weights` for output array.

First, we talk about `raw_values`

```py
>>> mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred, multioutput='raw_values')
array([0.5, 1. ])
```

The `array([0.5, 1. ])` is the original value of `mean_absolute_error()`. So if you put another `weight`, it will **calculate the average** output based on what you puts in `multioutput`.

If you don't give any value, the default is `[1,1]`.

```py
>>> mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)   # (0.5*1 + 1*1)/(1+1) = 0.75
0.75
```

OK, now if you give it another values like `[0.3, 0.7]`.

```py
>>> # (0.5*0.3+1*0.7)/(0.3+0.7) = 0.85
>>>mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred, multioutput=[0.3, 0.7])
0.85
```

**Note:**
Depending on the number of dimensions of `y_true`, `y_pred`, you must input the match length with `multioutput`. Example `y_pred = [[0, 2], [-1, 2], [8, -5]]` is `2-D` matrix, it will give you the output with 2 values like `[0.5, 1.]`. So you must give 2 values as weights for that output like `[0.3, 0.7]`

Comment: Use the example of the question, then it is perfect